# Logstash for windows .netcore application

Tags: c#, logging, logstash, error-logging, .net-core-rc2

I am a newbie to Logstash. I found it very interesting. But currently I am dealing with logging related to .NET core application. Am I right in using Logstash for my logging needs? I am confused after seeing that logstash is used only for server-side logging.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: do consider using [filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat) for simple log file shipping to `elasticsearch`. It works for us for our small scale setup, avoiding one more `logstash` components in our architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a typical logging library like [NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/master/README.md) and have the [LogStash Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-getting-started.html) properly configured so that logs are pushed to LogStash.

To make the most out of LogStash, it is highly preferable to log machine readable log entries over human readable logs. (ex: structured json over string messages, read more [here](https://stackify.com/what-is-structured-logging-and-why-developers-need-it/).)